# Does Cache control & pragma effects static content

Tags: java, caching, browser, pragma, no-cache

In my application I am using this to set no-cache at browser end.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
```

But the problem is I can still see at my browser end that some images are cached. So I was wondering that how this works.

Will it prevents HTML content coming as response to get cached whereas all static (.js, .css and images) gets cached.

And what can be the side effects of this if I use this for my complete application.